# Getting "Unexpected character '/' (code 47)" exception when running simple Odata4j consumer

Tags: odata4j

I am a beginner to odata4j. I am trying to run the following program using odata4j v0.7 library-

```
import org.core4j.Enumerable;
import org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumer;
import org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers;
import org.odata4j.core.OEntity;
import org.odata4j.examples.AbstractExample;

public class MyOdataTest extends AbstractExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ODataConsumer consumer = ODataConsumers.create("http://services.odata.org/OData.svc");
    Enumerable<OEntity> qList = consumer.getEntities("Categories").execute();
  }

}
```

However, when I run this in Eclipse, I get the following exception-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '/' (code 47) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at org.odata4j.core.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:11)
    at org.odata4j.stax2.staximpl.StaxXMLFactoryProvider2$StaxXMLEventReader2.nextEvent(StaxXMLFactoryProvider2.java:113)
    at org.odata4j.format.xml.EdmxFormatParser.parseMetadata(EdmxFormatParser.java:55)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataClient.getMetadata(AbstractODataClient.java:44)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer$CachedEdmDataServices.refreshDelegate(AbstractODataConsumer.java:212)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer$CachedEdmDataServices.getDelegate(AbstractODataConsumer.java:205)
    at org.odata4j.internal.EdmDataServicesDecorator.findEdmEntitySet(EdmDataServicesDecorator.java:46)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer$CachedEdmDataServices.findEdmEntitySet(AbstractODataConsumer.java:221)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer.getFeedCustomizationMapping(AbstractODataConsumer.java:235)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer.getEntities(AbstractODataConsumer.java:73)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer.getEntities(AbstractODataConsumer.java:69)
    at com.example.MyOdataTest.main(MyOdataTest.java:16)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '/' (code 47) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2032)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1117)
    at org.codehaus.stax2.ri.Stax2EventReaderImpl.nextEvent(Stax2EventReaderImpl.java:255)
    at org.odata4j.stax2.staximpl.StaxXMLFactoryProvider2$StaxXMLEventReader2.nextEvent(StaxXMLFactoryProvider2.java:111)
    ... 10 more
```

Please let me know if I am missing something. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is **resolved**. I was **using a wrong port number for proxy server** in jvm settings.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is **resolved**. I was **using a wrong port number for proxy server** in jvm settings.